# Passing Variables - undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

So i attempted to write my first patch of code that i can initialize in HTML and is passed through a JS file (attempting to learn how to write my own plugins).

notes:
JQuery is loaded onto this page already.
I can get the variables to appear in the console, but is it still translating it as a string?

This is the HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setSiteAppearance("$('#HeroHolder')",0);
    setSiteAppearance("$('#HeaderHolder')",400);
    setSiteAppearance("$('#FooterHolder')",700);
  })
```

This is the Javascript

```
function setSiteAppearance(elem,val){
    elem.fadeIn(600);
};
```

Comment: `"$('#HeroHolder')"` is a string, not a variable.  You don't want a string.

Comment: It seems you're trying to do `setSiteAppearance($('#HeroHolder'),0);` without quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setSiteAppearance("$('#HeroHolder')",0);
    setSiteAppearance("$('#HeaderHolder')",400);
    setSiteAppearance("$('#FooterHolder')",700);
  })
```

to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setSiteAppearance($('#HeroHolder'),0);
    setSiteAppearance($('#HeaderHolder'),400);
    setSiteAppearance($('#FooterHolder'),700);
})
```

You have to pass element but instead of you are passing string